# Compiling LibSSH2 with specific LibSSL

Tags: compiling, libraries, openssl, openssh

I have downloaded and compiled the latest version of libssl, the result of which is located at `/usr/local/ssl`. I want to compile libssh2 using the files in this folder, and to do that I've set the switch `--with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl`.

After performing `./configure --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl` and `make`, the resulting libssh2.so, according to the output of `ldd`, depends on the libssl found in the `/usr/lib64`, which is exactly what I don't want.

What can I do to force libssh2 to be compiled with the libssl I have in `/usr/local/ssl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compiled and installed libssl into the default `/usr/local` path, there is a `/usr/local/ssl`, but the lib is not in there; it's just directories like `certs` and `misc` -- stuff that other things would probably put in a `share` directory (e.g. `/usr/local/share/ssl`).

The actual library is installed in a normal place, `/usr/local/lib`.  Presuming you've *already* run `ldconfig` and that path is in a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, you should be able to then do:

```
ldconfig -p | grep ssl
```

And all the `=>` paths should be into `/usr/local/lib`.   If so, you can use:

```
--with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/
```

No `ssl` or `lib`, etc.  It should now be found properly.